# Web page embedded within Android application

Tags: android, android-layout

Gday all.

Basically what I'm trying to do is embed a webpage within my android application. I know the startActivity(launchBrowser) will open up the browser and display the page externally from the application. However what I want is the page to be displayed within the application say inside an EditText box or something similar. Is that possible at all and can is there a tutorial I can view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's done using a WebView. More info here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Answer (score 2):

I just followed the instructions from the developer reference on the android website but you basically:

Open up the java doc of the activity you want to have a webview in, and place this code in OnCreate()

```
    WebView webview = new WebView(this);
    setContentView(webview);
    webview.loadUrl("http://google.com/");
```